# Partial derivative question involving polar coordinates

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Given the plane polar coordinates x = r cos (θ), y = r sin (θ), show that
∂r/∂x*∂x/∂r + ∂θ/∂x*∂x/∂θ = 1

The solution I have says Xr = cos(θ) and Rx = cos(θ).

but I don't understand how you can't divide x =rcos(θ) by cos(θ).
and then Rx would be 1/cos(θ)?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From what you said $x=r\cos \theta$ and $y=r\sin \theta$. Also in the reverse direction $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\theta = \tan^{-1}(y/x)$. Now
First of all if $\theta=\theta(x,y)$, then
$$
-\frac{y}{x^2}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\tan\theta=(1+\tan^2\theta)\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}=\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}\Longrightarrow
\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}=-\frac{y}{r^2}=\frac{-\sin\theta}{r}
$$

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}=\cos\theta\\
\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}=-r\sin\theta\\
\frac{\partial r}{\partial x} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{x}{r} = \cos\theta\\
\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x} = -\frac{\sin\theta}{r}
\end{cases}
$$

Therefore
$$
\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}+
\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}=
\cos^2\theta
+\sin^2\theta=1
$$

Comment: Stealing my idea!

Comment: Really?! If I did it was unintentional. Sorry about that.

Comment: Just kidding of course! I was typing up the same thing, but hey, that's how this site works, and it's a good thing at that.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, we have $x=r\cos\theta$ $$\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{\cos\theta}$$
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}=\cos\theta$$
$$\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}=-\frac{\sin\theta}{r}$$
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}=-r\sin\theta$$
Now, set the corresponding values as follows $$\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\cdot \frac{\partial x}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}\cdot \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}$$$$=\left(\frac{1}{\cos\theta}\right)\left(\cos \theta\right)+\left(-\frac{\sin\theta}{r}\right)\left(-r\sin\theta\right)=\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$$

Comment: $\partial r/\partial x = \cos\theta$ and $\partial \theta/\partial x = - \sin\theta/r$.

Comment: How do you get the second partial derivative you stated?

Comment: Is it just me or is $(1/\cos\theta)\cdot\theta$ equal to $1$?

Comment: @Denis: Take partial derivatives of $x=r\cos\theta$ w.r.t. $r$ keeping $\theta$ constant as follows $$\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}=\cos\theta\frac{\partial r}{\partial r}=\cos\theta$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\phi: (r,\theta)\mapsto(x,y)$ be the polar to Cartesian map. We have the two Jacobian matrices $$
J_\phi=\pmatrix{{\partial x\over\partial r} & {\partial x\over\partial\theta} \\
{\partial y\over\partial r} & {\partial y\over\partial\theta}} \\ 
J_{\phi^{-1}}=\pmatrix{{\partial r\over\partial x} & {\partial r\over\partial y} \\
{\partial\theta\over\partial x} & {\partial\theta\over\partial y}}
$$ The given expression is the upper-left corner of the product $J_\phi J_{\phi^{-1}}=J_\phi J_\phi^{-1}=I$, so it must be equal to $1$.